# MacBook Pro: long time to wake from sleep, what could it be?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have a 2011 13-inch entry-level MacBook Pro, which was upgraded almost straight away to Lion.

I consider myself a careful, conscientious user, not installing things I don't need. However, recently, my MacBook Pro has started taking a very long time to wake from sleep.

I understand that it takes a long time to *go* to sleep, around 15-25 seconds usually. However, before, waking up was almost always instantaneous.

I'd like to know if there are any terminal or gui-based tools that help diagnose this problem. I recently checked `pmset -g assertions` and that seems to be fine. Any other tools I can use?

Comment: I assume this isn't the case, but your battery did not completely discharge in the meanwhile did it? Or does the MBP stay connected to the power source?

Comment: That's happened to me once or twice. It's a different process. A progress bar appears on the bottom of the screen, and a blurred-out picture appears of your mac as you left it. Basically... No that isn't the case, though it's a pretty good guess.

Comment: How about making a new user account, logging into it, then putting the machine to sleep and waking it up. Have you tried that? You'll be able to see if the problem is in your user account or deeper that way.

Comment: Did you by any chance fit extra RAM?  More RAM means a longer wake from sleep due to the sleepimage file (the size of which is based on the amount of RAM your system has).

Comment: @DanBarrett That would only be the case when the battery discharged completely. In regular sleep the RAM stays powered.

Comment: I'm actually already quite sure it's software. I'd like to know if there's any tool (gui or term) that can check what's causing the delay. I've already attempted to quit all applications running that I know of. Still takes long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my own question: it was a software issue after all. [Avatron's Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) server software installs a helper daemon that slows down the waking of my MacBook Pro.

After uninstalling it, the Mac wakes up a lot more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you or did you ever use a 3G dongle?

I had a Huawei 3G dongle and it wasn't the most graceful thing when it came to resuming from sleep. Sometimes the software would poll a USB device that wasn't plugged in and you couldn't do anything until it finished its routine.

Check your LaunchItems and LaunchAgents folder (Users/ and /Library/) for scripts that aren't supposed to be there or no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the case, no. I checked these folders.